# Как дописать код, чтобы в консоль выводилось имя с заглавной буквы?

Tags: javascript

Использовать методы toUpperCase и slice

```
const myName = prompt('Как Вас зовут?', '');
console.log('Здравствуйте, '.myName.toUpperCase + myName.slice(0));
```

В правильном направлении иду?

Comment: Ну почти. Ещё б самые азбучные основы подучить что бы не писать явные глупости

Comment: смотря что считать правильным направлением. пока код выглядит явным бредом

Comment: Не совсем. Значение  const не получится изменить уже.  И если выводить значение в ‘ ‘ кавычках оно выведет текст что находится в ковычках.

Comment: `'Здравствуйте, '.myName` Тут нужен плюс, а не точка; `.toUpperCase` метод не вызывается; `.toUpperCase + myName`, после `toUpperCase` нужен `slice(0, 1)`; в конце нужно сделать так: `myName.slice(1, myName.length)`, а **не** так: `myName.slice(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Если научиться гуглить, то можно попасть на [задачку](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/ucfirst), правда прежде чем к ней приступить, нужно прочитать [материал](https://learn.javascript.ru/string), а потом решить.
Если не можете самостоятельно решить, можете подсмотреть в решение.

В решении берётся первый символ переменной `myName[0]` и применяется метод `.toUpperCase()` ([подробнее о методе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)).
Далее прибавляется всё остальное, кроме первого символа - `myName.slice(1)`, при помощи метода `.slice()` ([подробнее о методе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

```js
const myName = prompt('Как Вас зовут?', '');

console.log('Здравствуйте, '+myName[0].toUpperCase()+myName.slice(1));
```

Comment: А я бы больше использовал `slice`, хорошее решение (у вас).